# Power automate error 404 when using shared mailbox when a new email arrives in a shared mailbox trigger

Tags: outlook, office365, power-automate, shared, power-automate-desktop

I was trying to create a power automate flow where it needs to be triggered if a new email arrives in a shared mailbox. I am facing an issue below when adding the folder of shared mailbox. I have access to the shared mailbox from my outlook id. additionally my outlook id is added in my connections of the flow.

> The dynamic invocation request failed with error: { "status": 404, "message": "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox. This error can occur for sandbox (test) accounts or for accounts that are on a dedicated (on-premise) mail server.\r\nclientRequestId: *********-*********\r\nserviceRequestId: **************", "error": { "message": "REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox. This error can occur for sandbox (test) accounts or for accounts that are on a dedicated (on-premise) mail server.", "code": "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI", "originalMessage": "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise." }, "source": "office365**********.net" }.[image: error 404 power automate]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, as the error message suggests, the shared mailbox may not be a cloud mailbox.

Clues that can indicate this are:

- No suggestions in Power Automate for Inbox subfolders
- Mailbox not available in Outlook Online

I'm working in an organization where we're working with multiple mailboxes that go back ages. To work them with Power Automate, we had to migrate them to the cloud with the IT department. Luckily this did not affect the daily use of the mailbox at all. However the technical limitations for the two differ (emails that can be sent per minute, unique recipients per day, recipients per email, accessibility with 3rd party software, external users and devices, etc.). Be sure to check these first.